# Get time from- new Date().getTime();

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the time of device. The code I am using is like this -

```
   const estimatedDeviceTimeMs = new Date().getTime();
    alert(new Date(estimatedDeviceTimeMs));
```

The result of above code is `Thu Jul 30 2020 12:01:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

I need to take out `12:01:54` in a variable and `GMT+0530` in another variable if possible.

Comment: That's a very long way to write `alert(new Date())`. Have you looked at the [available methods on the `Date` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Instance_methods)?

Comment: *"`getTime` returns a number representing the milliseconds elapsed between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.*"

Comment: thanks a ton, I am getting  the result

Comment: if you can answer, i'll accept it, regards

Answer (score 5):

`toTimeString` return the time. Then split by space to get time and timezone like below:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]);
console.log(date.toTimeString().split(" ")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```js
let date = new Date();
let time = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
let gmt = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[1];


console.log(`Time is ${time} and GMT is ${gmt} `);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bangla if you need it

```js
const parts = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('bn-in',{timeZoneName:'long'}).split(" ");
console.log(parts)
const estimatedDeviceTime = parts.slice(0,1) + " " +parts.slice(2)
console.log(estimatedDeviceTime)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call it by specific

```js
const time = new Date();
console.log(`${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}:${time.getSeconds()}`);
```